# JQuery Ajax call not working in If statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax

Is there a reason why my Ajax call will not work inside of an if statement? I may be doing something fundamentally wrong here because I don't have a lot of experience with JS or Ajax. Thanks

The working js function is:

```
function filter(varType, varValue) {
    var $products = $('#products');

    $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/filterSize/' + varValue)

    .success(function (data) {
        $products.empty(); // clear html from container
        var elt0 = '<div class="page-content"><h1 id="shoes">Shoes</h1></div>';
        $products.append(elt0);

        if (Object.keys(data.shoes).length === 0) {
            none = '<span class="noresults">No results</span>';
            $products.append(none);
        }

        else {
            var numItems = (Object.keys(data.shoes).length);
            for (index = 0; index < numItems ; ++index) {
                var elt1 = Flask.url_for("static", {"filename": data.shoes[index].img1});
                var elt2 = '<div id="item" class="col-md-4"><div class="products"><a href="shop/item/' + data.shoes[index].id + '"><h5>' + data.shoes[index].name + '</h5><img src="' + elt1 + '" alt="" width="200px" height="125px"></a></div>';
                $products.append(elt2);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But if I were to do this, it suddenly stops working:

```
function filter(varType, varValue) {
    var $products = $('#products');

    var x = 5
    var y = 6

    if (y > x) {
        $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/filterSize/' + varValue)
    }

    .success(function (data) {
        $products.empty(); // clear html from container
        var elt0 = '<div class="page-content"><h1 id="shoes">Shoes</h1></div>';
        $products.append(elt0);

        if (Object.keys(data.shoes).length === 0) {
            none = '<span class="noresults">No results</span>';
            $products.append(none);
        }

        else {
            var numItems = (Object.keys(data.shoes).length);
            for (index = 0; index < numItems ; ++index) {
                var elt1 = Flask.url_for("static", {"filename": data.shoes[index].img1});
                var elt2 = '<div id="item" class="col-md-4"><div class="products"><a href="shop/item/' + data.shoes[index].id + '"><h5>' + data.shoes[index].name + '</h5><img src="' + elt1 + '" alt="" width="200px" height="125px"></a></div>';
                $products.append(elt2);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You're missing a semi-colon after the line inside of the `if`

Comment: it stops working as it is invalid javascript, something you'd see in the developer tools console - what errors are you getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  if (y > x) {
            $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/filterSize/' + varValue)

        .success(function (data) {
            $products.empty(); // clear html from container
            var elt0 = '<div class="page-content"><h1 id="shoes">Shoes</h1></div>';
            $products.append(elt0);

            if (Object.keys(data.shoes).length === 0) {
                none = '<span class="noresults">No results</span>';
                $products.append(none);
            }

            else {
                var numItems = (Object.keys(data.shoes).length);
                for (index = 0; index < numItems ; ++index) {
                    var elt1 = Flask.url_for("static", {"filename": data.shoes[index].img1});
                    var elt2 = '<div id="item" class="col-md-4"><div class="products"><a href="shop/item/' + data.shoes[index].id + '"><h5>' + data.shoes[index].name + '</h5><img src="' + elt1 + '" alt="" width="200px" height="125px"></a></div>';
                    $products.append(elt2);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

This is valid syntax. You need to move the .success inside the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

You closed the curly brace of your `if-` statement too soon:

```
if (y > x) {
    $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/filterSize/' + varValue)
//} <-- TOO EARLY
    .success(function (data) {
        ....
    });
} <-- SHOULD BE HERE INSTEAD
```

End the `if` statement after the `.success()` callback.